# Can snowpipe streaming specify the warehouse when I use the sdk?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowpipe streaming sdk in Java.
I have lots of data in the S3 and try to send them to snowflake using the snowpipe streaming java sdk.

In the concept above, I am wondering that snowflake can determine the warehouse size so that the ingestion speed can be enhanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowpipe Streaming takes care of providing the resources to keep up with the volumne, no wh configuration needed:

> With Snowpipe Streaming’s serverless compute model, users can stream any data volume without managing a virtual warehouse. Instead, Snowflake provides and manages the compute resources, automatically growing or shrinking capacity based on the current Snowpipe Streaming load.
> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-streaming-billing

With that said, if you have files in S3 I don't see why you would choose to stream them row-by-row to Snowflake. Just use a traditional loading method for large batches:

> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/guides-overview-loading-data

Comment: Thanks. The reason I used the snowpipe streaming is that I don't care about the existing files. Just newly created file is ingested into snowflake. The S3 creates the put event notification when new file is uploaded, then I use the snowpipe streaming to ingest them in real time. In thse scenario, you also think that it is better to use traditional loading method such as copy into rather than snowpipe streaming?

Comment: Use "Snowpipe", but now "Snowpipe Streaming". The streaming part does rows, but classic Snowpipe will auto-ingest with the S3 notification. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3